# Want my app on Launchers Homescreen

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

Hey in the Launcher code I want one app to be shown on homescreen , in `AndroidManifest.xml`. I wrote these lines :

```
 <activity 
     android:name=".MyAppTabs" 
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
     android:label="MyApp"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_app">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

on adding these lines I am getting my app on the homescreen but it is not launching, but using Menu option I am able to launch my app...Any help??

Adiing more details.. I have default_workspace.xml file in xml folder where I am adding my app to favorite tag...

```
<favorite
    launcher:packageName="com.android.launcher"
    launcher:className="com.android.launcher.apps.MyAppTabs"
    launcher:screen="3"
    launcher:x="3"
    launcher:y="0" />
```

If any other information required ..Please tell me.

Comment: Hey what is your objective ?

Comment: automatically if your app installed from the market it will be on the home screen as shortcut. if you install it directly from eclipse it will not create the shortcut. and could you be more specific. i can't get if you are creating a launcher or you just need your app shortcut at the home screen.!

Comment: I am creating a luncher and I also have an app which is part of the launcher. I just want that app to be there in homescreen on installing my launcher on my device.

Answer (score 0):

This can be acheived only for the applications which is part of the same application (In this case your Launcher).

1. You should not start the activity of the application which you want to run inside of laucher
2. You should get the parent view where the applcation wants to be shown,
3. Get application design as single view or view group, consider this as child (this would be the child of launcher parent view)
4. Add child apllication view into launcher parent view.